# Rx.Net - Publish method missing first few items when subscribing to Cold Observable

Tags: system.reactive

Inspired by [Akavache](https://github.com/reactiveui/Akavache) I am trying to create a solution that provides me with an `IObservable<IArticle>`. The method essentially first try to get all the articles that are present in the database, then it tries to fetch updated articles from the webservice and as it is getting the latest articles from webservice it tries to save them back to the database.

Since the webservice is essentially a cold observable and I don't want to subscribe twice, I used `Publish` to connect to it. My understanding is that I am using the correct version of the `Publish` method, however, many times the method tend to miss first couple of Articles from the `GetNewsArticles`. This was observed through the UI and also the `Trace` calls added in the call below.

Apart from solving the problem, it would be great to also understand how to debug/test this code (apart from introducing DI to inject `NewsService`).

```cs
public IObservable<IArticle> GetContents(string newsUrl, IScheduler scheduler)
{
    var newsService = new NewsService(new HttpClient());
    scheduler = scheduler ?? TaskPoolScheduler.Default;

    var fetchObject = newsService
        .GetNewsArticles(newsUrl,scheduler)
        .Do(x => Trace.WriteLine($"Parsing Articles {x.Title}"));

    return fetchObject.Publish(fetchSubject =>
    {
        var updateObs = fetchSubject
            .Do( x =>                         
            {
                // Save to database, all sync calls
            })
            .Where(x => false)
            .Catch(Observable.Empty<Article>());

        var dbArticleObs = Observable.Create<IArticle>(o =>
        {
            return scheduler.ScheduleAsync(async (ctrl, ct) =>
            {
                using (var session = dataBase.GetSession())
                {
                    var articles = await session.GetArticlesAsync(newsUrl, ct);
                    foreach (var article in articles)
                    {
                        o.OnNext(article);
                    }
                }
                o.OnCompleted();
            });
        });

        return
            dbArticleObs                // First get all the articles from dataBase cache
                .Concat(fetchSubject    // Get the latest articles from web service 
                    .Catch(Observable.Empty<Article>())
                    .Merge(updateObs))  // Update the database with latest articles
                .Do(x => Trace.WriteLine($"Displaying {x.Title}"));
    });
}
```

**UPDATE - Added GetArticles**

```
public IObservable<IContent> GetArticles(string feedUrl, IScheduler scheduler)
{
    return Observable.Create<IContent>(o =>
    {
        scheduler = scheduler ?? DefaultScheduler.Instance;
        scheduler.ScheduleAsync(async (ctrl, ct) =>
        {
            try
            {
                using (var inputStream = await Client.GetStreamAsync(feedUrl))
                {
                    var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
                    {
                        IgnoreComments = true,
                        IgnoreProcessingInstructions = true,
                        IgnoreWhitespace = true,
                        Async = true
                    };

                    //var parsingState = ParsingState.Channel;
                    Article article = null;
                    Feed feed = null;

                    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(inputStream, settings))
                    {
                        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                        {
                            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                            if (reader.IsStartElement())
                            {
                                switch (reader.LocalName)
                                {
                                    ...
                                    // parsing logic goes here
                                    ...
                                }
                            }
                            else if (reader.LocalName == "item" &&
                                     reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement)
                            {
                                o.OnNext(article);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    o.OnCompleted();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                o.OnError(e);
            }

        });
        return Disposable.Empty;
    });
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Sharing the link to [source code](https://github.com/harvinders/RxTest/tree/original_issue) here.

Comment: Generally, when you do a `return Disposable.Empty;` on an `Observable.Create` then you are creating a poorly behaving query. Can you please provide a full definition (a [mcve]) and I'll see if I can refactor it without the `Observable.Create`?

Comment: minimal reproducible example would mean bringing in complete NewsService and Database. I would try to create one using a console app and publish it on github during next week, hopefully early next week.

Comment: I don't know if it would require a complete copy of all of those things. I would start a new projecy with the complete `GetContents` code and then include only the parts of `NewsService` and `Database` required to make that compile. It really doesn't have to be runnable, just compilable. Then it would be probable that I can refactor the code.

Comment: I have added a link to source code. The original_source branch has a compiling and working code. Also, I made some improvements based on your suggestions; they are in main branch.

Comment: @Enigmativity Just wondering if you got the chance to look at the code at https://github.com/harvinders/RxTest/tree/original_issue or the improved version at https://github.com/harvinders/RxTest/tree/main

Comment: Yes, I did. I've hit an issue with async and enumerables that I wanted to clear. It's fairly chucky code and hard to refactor. It should be a lot more modular to make the code easier to refactor.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things I don't like about your code. I assume `NewsService` is an `IDisposable` as it takes an `HttpClient` (which is disposable). You're not doing a proper clean up.

Also, you haven't provided a complete method - because you've tried cutting it down for the question - but that makes it hard to reason about how to rewrite the code.

That said, the one thing that sticks out to me as quite horrid looking is the `Observable.Create`. Can you please try this code instead and see if it helps things work for you?

```
    var dbArticleObs =
        Observable
            .Using(
                () => dataBase.GetSession(),
                session =>
                    from articles in Observable.FromAsync(ct => session.GetArticlesAsync(newsUrl, ct))
                    from article in articles
                    select article);
```

Now, if that does, try rewriting `fetchObject` to use the same `Observable.Using` when newing up the `NewService.

In any case, it would be good if you could provide a complete implementation of `GetContents`, `NewsService` and your `dataBase` code in your question.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right about the `HttpClient`. I have added the code for `NewsService` at the end of the question. Could you please explain why  `Observable.Create` implementation is wrong and how does your proposal solves it?